# В чем проблема при работе с методом dig?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Документация: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-dig

Запускаю `rails c`, пишу:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(foo: { bar: { baz: 1 } })
```

И далее:

```
params.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)
```

Эти две строки взяты со страницы, ссылка на которую приведена выше.

В результате я получаю `nil`.

При работе с `Hash` все нормально. При работе с `ActionController::Parameters` возникает проблема. Эта проблема у меня возникает и внутри Rails приложения.

Нужно ваше мнение на этот счет.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @Kromster текст вопроса прочитайте, пожалуйста. Там все есть. Если вы никак не связаны с Ruby / Rails и не понимаете проблему, то это не повод писать комментарий.

Comment: Вы же сами просили - *"Нужно ваше мнение на этот счет."*. Вот я свое мнение и написал вам .. не хотите извлекать из него пользу - дело ваше.

Comment: @Colibri Вы используете 5 версию Rails? Потому что у меня в 4 `dig` работает как ожидалось.

Comment: @Ainar-G ответ уже написан. Будьте внимательнее в следующий раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://eileencodes.com/posts/actioncontroller-parameters-now-returns-an-object-instead-of-a-hash/

```
params.to_unsafe_h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)
```